# Congratulations Darin Dimitrov for reaching a million reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, users, top-users

Today, Thursday, 11 August 2022, I just noticed that Darin Dimitrov reached 1 million points of reputation on Stack Overflow.

Darin Dimitrov loves writing code and is really passionate about it.

[image]

And he is an [MVP](https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-US/Overview) since 2011.

He have been using Microsoft technologies since the early 1990s. His primary interest is .NET development.

He joined Stack Overflow in the year 2008 and has posted an astonishing 21,436 answers.

I don't think I have had the chance to have Darin Dimitrov answer any of my questions, but I have definitely used his answers to learn something new.

It is an incredible milestone to achieve this because it takes a lot of effort, challenge, and patience in a daily routine to continue this process.

It inspires people like me and others to reach this stage.

So finally thanks Darin Dimitrov, congratulations and keep it up with this great job!!!!!!