# We are no longer allowing congratulatory posts on Meta for users reaching 1 million rep or less

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta

This is an announcement that we have made the decision to disallow congratulatory posts on Meta for users reaching a million rep. We understand that reaching a million reputation is an impressive achievement worth celebrating, but these types of posts are being increasingly common and do not provide any meaningful discussions or value to the community and they will be deleted. Additionally, it's not possible to cherry-pick exceptions for certain users while disallowing others, so we will apply this rule across the board.

Some examples (*10k required to view*):

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361741/legendary-user-with-1-million-reputation-jon-skeet
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416786/balus-c-just-reached-1-million
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419768/congratulations-darin-dimitrov-for-reaching-a-million-reputation
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419770/congratulations-darin-dimitrov-for-reaching-a-million-reputation
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420171/congratulations-darin-dimitrov-for-reaching-1-000-000-reputation
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421919/congratulations-martijn-pieters-for-reaching-a-million-reputation
- etc.,
- (*and the latest*) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424358/congratulations-martijn-pieters-t-j-crowder-darin-dimitrov-and-marc-gravell

Quoting Cody in a comment on a previously deleted post on this:

> Do you plan to post a question for every person who reaches 1 million reputation? Is this really useful or interesting to anyone? The milestone has been reached before, multiple times. It's not novel or unique anymore. For people who care about reputation, there are plenty of ways to see this, including the reputation leaderboards. Reputation is not what Meta is about.
> – [2022-08-11 10:29:21Z](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419768/congratulations-darin-dimitrov-for-reaching-a-million-reputation#comment922107_419768)

**Moving forward we ask that you do not post reputation congratulatory messages here on Meta.**

We encourage you to continue to celebrate their achievements and milestones, but we ask that you do so within the appropriate spaces, such as via social media, on your own blog, or in [The Meta Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197438/the-meta-room).

Comment: On the other hand, what harm do these posts do? One million rep is still one heck of an achievement...

Comment: Does it only concern meta SO or also the main meta SE?

Comment: @Elikill58 yeah, that is a good idea! Let's annoy Cody by posting these on MSE where he can't do a thing about it. I'll start flagging the posts here for migration ....

Comment: Quoting my own comment from one of the deleted posts: _"At some point we will just have to stop assuming that a user gaining 1 million reputation points is a huge deal. Especially because some of these cases are of indiscriminate answering with little care for curation activity, a behavior which is detrimental in the long term."_

Comment: Shouldn't this post be featured?

Comment: IMO there should be a congratulatory post for X number of useful answers, not based on reputation score. Or X number of review actions. Things that actually show you're part of the solution and can inspire people. A million rep is so meaningless by comparison.

Comment: This is interesting. Is there any actual argument behind this decision apart from million-rep fatigue? Has anyone tried to project when the next million-rep congratulatory post may occur? Are we special-casing a few posts per decade here?

Comment: At the moment, @FrédéricHamidi , either [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) or [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill) would likely be next. *If* we use the reputation they've gained so far this year, then CommonsWare in a little under a year and Greg in about 16~ months. These are, however, wild estimations; CommonWare's activity seems to have got lower of late, for example.

Comment: @Elikill58 Strictly speaking, we only set policy for Stack Overflow, so this only applies to Meta.SO.  When Shog9 or Glorfindel eventually reach 1 million reputation on Meta.SE, congratulations may indeed be in order.  But definitely don't post congratulations for Stack Overflow users on Meta.SE, as that would simply be off-topic.  It also doesn't apply to other per-site metas; other sites may wish to set their own policy for their own meta sites.

Comment: I am absolutely delighted to see this post! Does celebrating reputation gains do any harm?  I believe it does.  It distracts from the importance of "curation" (which earns dedicated users no direct rep gains). I don't like it when I see rep celebration outside of SO either (e.g. on social media) because it reinforces the gamification of this network. We need to be celebrating those that are doing a terrific job of improving the Researcher eXperience. This is much more nuanced and harder to track, but infinity more important than "trust points" that we've seen some >100K users "farm".

Comment: @mickmackusa then we should fix the real problem - good curation not being rewarded with reputation!

Comment: @E_net4 If this activity is not congratulation-worthy *then it shouldn't give a million reputation points*.

Comment: I agree with the sentiments that rep is overrated relative to curation, but looking at [the charts](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow), there are 4 users in the 900k-1m range and 8 users in the 800k-900k range so I don't think banning celebration posts is really a big win. We're saving, like, 12 posts a year or so at the very most? Seems like spending the time writing these threads is better spent in the queues.

Comment: While I generally agree that we don't need more of them - this action seems like it's contentious enough that I'd offer a compromise solution as an alternative. Instead of banning them outright, create a new tag on meta: [meta-tag:reputation-milestone]. Every milestone announcement can then be tagged with that tag, and anyone who doesn't want to see them can ignore said tag.

Comment: This is kind of a bummer – a lot of the users being celebrated in these posts are well-loved members of the village and they've accomplished a real milestone. People reaching seven-figure reputation are not getting there by accident or fluke. 1M rep means a lot of investment in our community. Their achievements are our achievements, and are worth celebrating.

Comment: @user253751 That is more of an unwanted side effect of gamification in this platform than something really intended. Before a user reaches 25k, they will be gathering privileges for contributing to the site. After that, while reaching a million isn't very useful, there wasn't a reason to impose a reputation cap either. It is also true that not all ways of garnering reputation are useful.

Comment: @mickmackusa "It distracts from the importance of "curation"" That's just evidence of what a horrible mess the Q&A format is for meta. If users get distracted by something, that means that the site has failed to categorize posts in a sensible way. I'm pretty sure everyone agrees that having a social media "feed" constantly barfing out new, completely unrelated posts in an unsorted mess is very distracting. The problem isn't the contents of individual posts but the broken-by-design format of meta. Huge mistake thinking the Q&A format is good for meta just because it's good for the main site.

Comment: Also if nobody cares to explain who "we" are then edit the post and replace it with "someone". Unless Samuel has a habit of speaking of themselves in plural and making unanimous discussions about what content that is allowed on meta, but I doubt that is the case.

Comment: I don't really get the backlash against the policy. Those posts bear no useful information, do not seek any input from the community at large, and promote bad practices such as answering anything that moves to top things off. They also cause tension each time they appear. Why can't we just ... not have them?

Comment: They also target a specific user, and are likely to attract downvotes/backlash against said user.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine Do they cause tension each time they appear? Why? I only remember people upvoting and saying "Thank you" and "Well done".

Comment: The last few were downvoted pretty heavily before they were eventually deleted

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica I remember there been strife as to whether they are even on-topic on MSO, as well as them having a very split reception (not the first ones, mostly the newer ones). Although, unfortunately, I can't easily check my memory as most are deleted now, and I am yet to reach 10K+ to view them - I've asked for help with that and will circle back with more explanation if it is confirmed (or not).

Comment: Thanks, @OlegValteriswithUkraine (and Kevin), you've already told me what I wanted to understand. I had missed the latest ones and didn't know about the downvotes.

Comment: @Machavity Does your edit mean, like TheMaster's answer requests, congratulatory posts for reputation milestones _over_ 1 million are still allowed? The announcement body doesn't really reflect that (it still says milestones in general are disallowed). If that is what your title edit means, two things: 1) the body should be updated to reflect that, and 2) what counts as a milestone? 1,000,001? 1,100,000? 1,500,000? Or just multiples of 1 million (e.g. 2 million, 3 million, etc.)? And if every million is fine, will it only remain so until we start seeing 10+ users reaching that threshold, too?

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica there's a bit more stats and discussion [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56269385#56269385) if you are interested. Seems like my memory served me right - far from every such post was universally applauded. Although I wish we could provide a more data-driven response.

Comment: I have posted an answer which should hopefully clear this up for the future

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We had a discussion about this internally and I think the frustration at having yet another question pop up boiled over here. The problem is that people make posts about this haphazardly. They're great for community recognition... but not much else. But, it really **IS** a big deal. 1M points is hard to come by. As Henry Ecker noted, [other sites use roll-up posts for that](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19135/congratulations-the-big-thread) and it makes a lot of sense here. So, to that end

1. We're not allowing any further standalone 1M celebration posts
2. [We now have a rollup post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424425/the-stack-overflow-1-million-points-club). It lists all 7 folks with 1M and we'll let it run until it hits 50 listed. New answers can bump it as needed.
3. At some point in 2030 or thereabouts, Jon Skeet will hit 2M. We can have another celebratory rollup post at that point.

Probably should have been clearer up front on that. Please accept our apologies. Hopefully this solves both sets of desires.

Comment: Can we create a post for the first user to hit 2M, or specifically wait until Jon Skeet does?

Comment: @francescalus With the rep cap, that won't happen for at least 7 years. Jon is the leader of that pack

Comment: This does look like a great compromise (I mean look at the current question's up/down ratio), thanks!

Answer (score 10):

> we have made the decision

Who are "we"?

- The company? If so then why are you sent to announce this instead of staff?
- The community? If so where is the meta discussion with community consensus leading to this decision?
- The moderator team? If so, since when do moderators unanimously get to decide what kind of content that's allowed on meta?

And seriously, what harm did these posts do. "The users must under no circumstances try to form a sense of belonging to a community" or what?

Comment: And for the record I don't really care about these kind of congratulation posts one way or the other but I get upset when some anonymous "we" decide that they have the right to dictate what gets to be posted on meta. I recognize that the company SO has the authority to do so, but in that case at least be straight-forward about it by having a CM making an official statement.

Comment: CMs generally don't set site-level policy like this (although you can appeal to them via the Contact Us form if you want). That's within the purview of moderators. If you have gripes with the policy, voice them (had this been a real dictatorship we'd have just locked the post and not allowed any discussion at all). But we've reached the level where the achievement is no longer remarkable and we're getting more and more noisy posts about it. Feel free to disagree.

Comment: "The community? If so where is the meta discussion" - meta is not "the community". It is a very vocal and small group of regulars.

Comment: @Gimby Like in any democratic instance, it is up to the individuals to participate or not - it is an active choice. Nobody is prevented (yet) from voicing their opinion on meta.

Answer (score 8):

If 1 million is becoming common, I believe  congratulatory posts for future milestones such as 3 million, 5 million and 10 million should be allowed. Each such milestone congratulatory posts can be restricted to a maximum of say, three users. Therefore, only the first 3 to reach each milestone will be celebrated in Meta.

Comment: agreed, even two million is fine

Comment: @SamuelLiew Because new milestones are less distracting, provide meaningful discussions and are not cherry picked to the first user reaching them? Does this seem consistent or rational to you?

Comment: Doesn't this just mean that the same few users will receive congratulations again and again? The first ones to 1M will likely also be the first ones to 2M, and so on.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship eh, there have been a few to hit 1m who did it so quickly that they very well could outpace the top 3 if they had continued at that rate.

Comment: @KevinB Fast guns, I assume? So the ones that many would prefer not to congratulate?

Answer (score 4):

There was a reason to celebrate a user reaching a million reputation points when the concept was new. On the other hand, there is no reason to recommend or incentivize grinding for reputation, and these "questions"¹ do just that.
Reputation is indeed not what Meta is about, and I would like to stress the potential **misguidance** that we are introducing by posting a congratulatory post every time a user reaches this milestone.

In fact, if we continue to post these, we will also potentially be highlighting users who prefer posting as many new answers as they can, with little concern for identifying duplicates or otherwise curating questions before answering them. This behavior can be detrimental to the site, as it contributes to keeping more low quality questions visible on the site, dispersing the same content to multiple posts rather than focusing the knowledge onto key questions.

So, this decision may feel very unilateral and strict, but remember that this will become slowly but steadily more likely to expose the platform's carebears, for better or for worse. As much as it is understood the enormous time and effort is required to achieve this milestone, and regardless of whether this unilateral decision came from the moderator team or higher up in the chain, it isn't a decision worth being upset about.

---

¹ Yep, these are not even questions. We happen to have public service announcements ([psa](/questions/tagged/psa)), but we would be starting a specific precedent of announcing a relatively repetitive kind of event which, for the reasons specified above and here, are no longer worth announcing in this fashion.

Comment: There's so much projection in this answer that I don't even know where to start. _"recommend or incentivize grinding for reputation"_, really? "Grinding"? Do you know how dismissive this is of people's immense effort that went into writing tens of thousands of answers? I wish such "questions" would incentivize more people to try their hardest to spend only a little amount of their free (or employer-sponsored, I don't judge) time into writing as many correct, insightful, inspiring answers as they can.

Comment: @CodeCaster Perceive what you wish of this answer, but the fact is that some of the users that one would be celebrating are among the [FGITW group](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308302), and for the best of both parts, it is best that they are not exposed as such. Unless you propose to only announce the "good ones" instead, but this would be another slippery slope.

Comment: That the effort was spent producing less than stellar content doesn't diminish the amount of effort spent; rather, it diminishes the value of the result.

Comment: Look who wrote the highest-voted answer to the question you link to. Unclear/duplicate-answerers are going to be there anyway, I don't see VonC nor Torek stopping to answer each and every goddamn Git question that hits the site. For all others attempting to do the same, there's still downvotes. Forbidding a handful of "congrats" posts a year isn't going to change the minds of tens of thousands of rep-hunters.

Comment: "there's still downvotes" ... Downvotes have no effect on high reppers. I would consider these users to be >10K reppers.  They know that someone will come along and upvote eventually and there will be a net gain.  I haven't seen the contributions of all of the 1M users, but I have seen Linoff answering the same questions over and over.  This is because I typical perform "heap curation" -- I search for many of the same asked question, assess them as a group, then hammer them toward a canonical. I have certainly voted to close Linoff-answered pages with Linoff-answered pages.

Answer (score -3):

> these types of posts are being increasingly common

Meta is nearing 50,000 questions. What harm do these posts do, let there be 50, being 0,1% of total questions? A type of post becoming more common is not a problem in and of itself.

> and do not provide any meaningful discussions or value to the community

Do community cohesion and motivation for others to have something to strive for not have value?

Comment: I mean... i don't see any value in congratulating people for spamming answers on low quality/duplicate questions, personally

Comment: Please tell me the trick to spamming answers on low quality/duplicate questions, getting to a million rep and not getting yourself banned or bored/burned out. Trust me, I've tried.

Comment: I've slept since then, i stopped that at 20k rep many years ago

Comment: Please don't try that, btw. It's a mess to clean up; it also prevents lots of automatic clean up.